# vb.net async stream write/read problems

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

I’m after some help with a problem i have been working on for the past few days but i can't seem to get it to work correctly.

I have multiple clients connecting to a server, the server needs to keep a list of connected clients and remove them from the list if the client disconnects, I have this bit working correctly.

Once a client is connected the server may call upon the client for some information about its state by sending a few bytes of data to which the client responds with 2 bytes of data. Based on this response the server will complete any one of number of different tasks.

I have had this working synchronously, though now I am trying to make the function asynchronous and I’m running in to an issue. The best I can tell my function that request the information from the client is completing before the client responds and is returning incorrect data, if I print the data received from the client I can see it is the correct information.

This is my 1st time working with asynchronous functions and connections so it’s highly likely I’ve got it completely wrong, I have looked at lots of example code but I can seem to find any that sheads any light on my issue.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
  'create the collection instance to store connected clients
    Private clients As New List(Of TcpClient)
    'declare a variable to hold the listener instance
    Private listener As TcpListener
    'declare a variable to hold the cancellation token source instance
    Private tokenSource As CancellationTokenSource
    Private recvTsk As Task
    Private Rreply As New List(Of Byte)



    Private Async Sub startTCPListenerServer()

'get port from ini file
        Dim netPort = SettingsIniFile.GetString("Setup", "NetworkPort", "")



        While True
            'create a new cancellation token source instance
            tokenSource = New CancellationTokenSource
            'create a new listener instance bound to the desired address and port
            listener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, netPort)
            'start the listener
            listener.Start()
            While True
                Try
                    Dim client As TcpClient = Await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync

                    clients.Add(client)
                    Dim clientIP As String = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(clientIP)



                    Try
                        'begin reading from the client's data stream
                        Using stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream
                            Dim buffer(client.ReceiveBufferSize - 1) As Byte
                            Dim read As Integer = 1

                            'if read is 0 client has disconnected
                            While read > 0

                                recvTsk = New Task(Sub()

                                                       For i = 0 To read - 1

                                                           'data recived at this point is correct 
                                                           Rreply.Add(buffer(i))
                                                       Next


                                                   End Sub, tokenSource.Token)


                                read = Await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, tokenSource.Token)

                                recvTsk.Start()

                            End While
                            'client gracefully closed the connection on the remote end
                        End Using
                    Catch ocex As OperationCanceledException
                        'the expected exception if this routines's async method calls honor signaling of the cancelation token
                        '*NOTE: NetworkStream.ReadAsync() will not honor the cancelation signal
                    Catch odex As ObjectDisposedException
                        'server disconnected client while reading
                    Catch ioex As IOException
                        'client terminated (remote application terminated without socket close) while reading
                    Finally
                        'ensure the client is closed - this is typically a redundant call, but in the
                        'case of an unhandled exception it may be necessary
                        'remove the client from the list of connected clients
                        clients.Remove(client)

                        client.Close()
                        ListBox1.Items.Remove(clientIP)

                        'remove the client's task from the list of running tasks
                        'clientTasks.Remove(client.Task)
                    End Try


                Catch odex As ObjectDisposedException
                    'listener stopped, so server is shutting down
                    Exit While
                End Try

            End While


            For i As Integer = clients.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                clients(i).Close()
            Next
            tokenSource.Dispose()

        End While

        'signal any processing of current clients to cancel (if listening)
        tokenSource.Cancel()
        'abort the current listening operation/prevent any new connections
        listener.Stop()
        'End If


    End Sub



    Async Function sendToPod(message() As Byte, podNum As Integer) As Task(Of Byte)

        If clients.Count = 0 Then

        Else
            Dim podIP As String

'get ip address as string from ini file
                podIP = SettingsIniFile.GetString("NetworkSettings", "Pod" & podNum & "IP", "")


            Dim currentClient As TcpClient = Nothing

            For Each client As TcpClient In clients

                Dim clientIP As String = (CType(client.Client.RemoteEndPoint, IPEndPoint).Address.ToString())

                If clientIP = podIP Then
                    currentClient = client
                End If
            Next

            If currentClient IsNot Nothing Then

                'get the current client, stream, and data to write

                Dim stream As NetworkStream = currentClient.GetStream


                Dim buffer() As Byte = message

                'wait for the data to be sent to the remote 

                Await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)


                recvTsk.Wait()

                Return Rreply(1)

            End If

        End If


    End Function

    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Me.TextBox1.Text = Await sendToPod({"&HAB", "&HAD", "&HFF", "&HFF"}, 1)
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It might be that an exception is being raised, but with those empty Catch statements you will not be informed what it is.

Comment: Please provide a small example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It’s defiantly not throwing an exception as the client doesn’t drop from the server, the blank catch statements are related to handling the client connections and disconnections, not reading from/writing to the stream, these exceptions will be correctly handled in the finial app but haven’t added them in the code example.  As the connect/disconnect side of it is workin the program remains within the while read > 0 loop, which has no try catch statements, additionally the data is coming back correctly but only after the Sendtopod function has finished and returned garbage.